# Why my iptables script is not working propertly?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

i have a PC whit 2 interfaces in the same subnet. I need to block all trafic from one IP to one interface. Also i need to accept connections from every ip on that subnet on both interfaces.

Can someone tell me what i make wrong?

This is my script.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.8.32 -j DROP
```

Comment: What is the network interface configuration on the box? Please also add the current script to your question. Please edit the question, do not add information as comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you use `iptables -A`, the rule you are adding is put at the end of the chain. As soon as one rule matches, iptables executes the action (DROP, ACCEPT) and stops processing the remaining rules.

On your case, as soon as the IP `192.168.8.32` reaches iptables, it sees the rule `192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT`, the IP matches the rule, and it accepts the connection. The `DROP` rule never gets evaluated.

You must put the `DROP` rules first, and the `ACCEPT` after them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser, but your solution not work for me

Comment: I change the order of the ACL but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should place more precise `DROP` rules at the beginning. Otherwise, the 
 more global `ACCEPT` rules will take precedence.

Second, if you have 2 incoming interfaces for same subnet, you should have a `DROP` rule for both incoming interfaces.

Here is what i would suggest :

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.8.32 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.8.32 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But your solution is not what I'm looking. I need to block only one interface eth1. When I use your solution only with that interface firewall just not work 

Comment: So leave out the line `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.8.32 -j DROP`. Answers should be understood ... not only copy/pasted.

Comment: Man Thanks, but i just did that. I only use the line for eth1